# How to avaid duplicate composable(SOME_ROUTE) for one navController.navigate(SOME_ROUTE) in Android Jetpack Compose NavController?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I am developing Android Jetpack Compose app following Jetnews demo application https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/JetNews and it implements navigation in 3 modules:

Main composable https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/JetNews/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetnews/ui/JetnewsApp.kt contains `NavGraph` implementation `JetnewsNavGraph`:

```
            JetnewsNavGraph(
                appContainer = appContainer,
                isExpandedScreen = isExpandedScreen,
                navController = navController,
                openDrawer = { coroutineScope.launch { sizeAwareDrawerState.open() } },
            )
```

This NavGraph instance https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/JetNews/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetnews/ui/JetnewsNavGraph.kt contains list of actions-composables that are called by `NavController` internally and that define what should happen in each navigation case. Usually the code instantiates `ViewModel` and its respective `Route/Screen`.

```
    composable(JetnewsDestinations.INTERESTS_ROUTE) {
        val interestsViewModel: InterestsViewModel = viewModel(
            factory = InterestsViewModel.provideFactory(appContainer.interestsRepository)
        )
        InterestsRoute(
            interestsViewModel = interestsViewModel,
            isExpandedScreen = isExpandedScreen,
            openDrawer = openDrawer
        )
    }
```

And then there is definition of navigation actions https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/JetNews/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetnews/ui/JetnewsNavigation.kt. These navigation actions are called from the events (e.g. `onClick`) in `composables` and these navigation actions call `navController` commands themselves:

```
val navigateToInterests: () -> Unit = {
    navController.navigate(JetnewsDestinations.INTERESTS_ROUTE) {
        popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
            saveState = true
        }
        launchSingleTop = true
        restoreState = true
    }
}
```

So - the whole architecture of Jetpack navigation is:

```
onClick() 
-> navigationActions.navigateToInterests 
-> navController.navigate(INTERESTS_ROUTE) 
-> composable(INTERESTS_ROUTE) [called by navController internally]
```

But there is problem with my copy/my implementation: I have `onClick()` and one `navController.navigate(SOME_ROUTE)` calls and exactly two `composable(SOME_ROUTE)` calls. I am tracing everything by `Log.i(...)` and I clearly see that this is a case. I am not calling `composable(SOME_ROUTE)` directly, it is called by navController internally and that is why I have no real control. I can control this by the additional arguments, when my app calls `navController.navigate(SOME_ROUTE)` but otherwise such duplicate internal call can be some error inside navController as well.

So - why navController is making those duplicate calls? Is it normal practice or is it error inside navController or is it error in my arguments that I am passing in `navController.navigate(SOME_ROUTE)`?

I have made Google search `navcontroller duplicate calls` and there are interesting articles https://proandroiddev.com/duplicate-android-navigation-bug-or-feature-5df370440c83 and [Navigation controller gets called twice inside livedata observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58904454/navigation-controller-gets-called-twice-inside-livedata-observer) but they are not relevant to my problem, because they both are concerned with the duplicate call of `navController.navigate(SOME_ROUTE)`. My situation is different - I have one programmatic `navController.navigate(SOME_ROUTE)` call and navController issues 2 `composable(INTERESTS_ROUTE)` calls for that one call. Of course - I am looking ways how to avoid the second `composable(INTERESTS_ROUTE)` call.

Comment: It may be possible that there is duplicate recomposition that resembles call of composable(INTERESTS_ROUTE)

Comment: The second call usually appears 0.4 or 0.6 or even full 1.0 seconds after the initial call - at least the Logcat/Log.i(...) messages have such time span.

Comment: If I undersood your concern your code on a composable may run multiple times and you do not have much controll over it. You may have a look on this arcticle: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model

Comment: Thx, I have gond through that article. Is there a way to trace the recomposition of some part? E.g. I can have Column elements, is there possible to put some debugging code that detects that Column or some of its children have recomposed? Maybe I should open another question?

Comment: There is some material about tracking/debugging already https://www.jetpackcompose.app/articles/how-can-I-debug-recompositions-in-jetpack-compose

Comment: Since you work with compose it is perfectly fine the code to run multiple times, where is the problem I do not understand? If you need heavy calculations you should use a viewmodel parallel with compose and listen to changes (mutable state).In general if you work with compose the code may run multiple times and without order as well :)

Comment: With due respect I strongly disagree. 1) Code under consideration is composable(JetnewsDestinations.INTERESTS_ROUTE) {...} - its body includes retrieval of ViewModel and the screen. ... well - I am starting to see - ViewModel is created only upon the first invocation of viewModel(...) and InterestsRoute can be recomposed repeatedly... well, indeed maybe it is not harmful to experience the multiple executions of this code... but isn't it corrupting backstack?

Comment: 2) while multiple recomposition can be tolerated and its execution can be in unpredictable time and space, the mere execution (yes/no) should be predictable and its number should be minimized indeed, at least for the sake of optimization.